# Passing an array to another function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reactjs

Simpleish react question that is evading me for a second:

```
  readData: function(){
    var readFromCpDev1 = firebase.database().ref('environments/' + 'cp-dev1');
    var envUsersArray = [];
    readFromCpDev1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      envUsersArray.push(snapshot.val())
      return envUsersArray;
    });
    console.log(envUsersArray, 'hey');
  },

anotherfunc: function(){
}
```

I have this function and I want to return `envUsersArray` and use it wherever. Obviously at the moment it is returning a blank array as the `readData` function is not in the scope of the snapshot function.
How can I pass it down to the `readData` function and then use it inside another function such as `anotherfunc`

I know I probably need to call `this.` somewhere but the logic isn't quite coming to me at the mo

Comment: Is `readFromCpDev1.on` asynchronous?

Comment: @changed I believe so. at least according to my understanding from the firebase docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using Promises.

```
  readData: function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      var readFromCpDev1 = firebase.database().ref('environments/' + 'cp-dev1');
      var envUsersArray = [];
      readFromCpDev1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        envUsersArray.push(snapshot.val())
        resolve(envUsersArray);
      });
    });
  },

  anotherfunc: function(){
    this.readData().then(function(arr) {
      //do stuff here
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may return a promise that will resolve with value that is retrieved asynchronously:

```
  readData: function() {
    var readFromCpDev1 = firebase.database().ref('environments/' + 'cp-dev1');
    var envUsersArray = [];
      return new Promise(function(success) {
      readFromCpDev1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        envUsersArray.push(snapshot.val())
        success(envUsersArray);
      }
    });
  },

  anotherfunc: function(){
   this.readData().then(function(result) {
     console.log(result);
   });
  }
```

Comment: It's actually same as what @Pavel Staselun answered.